# Can Reminder be updated for windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7

Would appreciate you help for the following. 
I have created a reminder but I want to update it before or after the reminder nofiticaton has activated. here the code.
Problem : it wont work even if there is no compilation error for this code.

```
var Myreminders = ScheduledActionService.GetActions()
                .Where(a => a.BeginTime.Month == month);


            foreach (Reminder r in Myreminders)
            {
                string strMyRmd;

               strMyRmd = r.Name.ToString();

                if ( strMyRmd == "MyName1" )
                {
                    r.Title = "Today Shopping";
                }             

            }
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean, "it doesn't work, **and** there is no compilation error"? What does "it doesn't work" mean exactly?

Comment: Typo error. I have edited my message. what I meant was that even there was no compilation error for the code, it wont work such that it would get updated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe (I can't test this from my computer but have confirmed this works with Background Agents) that you need to find your Reminder, remove it from the scheduled action service, update and re add it.

```
var reminder = (Reminder)ScheduledsActionService.Find("MyReminder");

ScheduledActionService.Remove("MyReminder");

reminder.Title = "Updated Title";

ScheduledActionService.Add(reminder);
```

Comment: I tried your method. It wont work. It deleted the reminder and wont add or replace it when I query with  reminders = ScheduledActionService.GetActions<Reminder>() to show all reminders.

Answer (score 0):

According to the remarks section in [ScheduledActionService.GetActions Method documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh220821%28v=vs.92%29.aspx):

> The Scheduled Action Service does not maintain a reference to the
>   objects returned by this method, and therefore the properties of the
>   objects are not updated to reflect the current state after the call to
>   GetActions. To obtain an object that is updated by the system as its
>   state changes, use Find(String) instead.

So, just use [Find(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.scheduledactionservice.find%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: ohh, damn, I didn't saw te question date... I guess the issue had been solved long time ago, sorry for bothering...